# Null Pointer Exception when setText - TextView

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

I have a fragment in MainActivity and try to setText in fragment, but when I try to do it I get Null Pointer Exception. I checked spelling but it seems okay. I debug app and check these variables but it doesnt seem they are null.

[image]

The exception appear in first line of clearText() method.

```
 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sun, container, false);

        sunRiseTime = v.findViewById(R.id.sunRiseTime);
        sunRiseAzimuth = v.findViewById(R.id.sunRiseAzimuth);
        sunSetTime = v.findViewById(R.id.sunSetTime);
        sunSetAzimuth = v.findViewById(R.id.sunSetAzimuth);
        duskTime = v.findViewById(R.id.duskTime);
        dawnTime = v.findViewById(R.id.dawnTime);

        return v;
    }

private void clearText(){
        sunSetTime.setText("");
        sunSetAzimuth.setText("");
        sunRiseTime.setText("");
        sunRiseAzimuth.setText("");
        duskTime.setText("");
        dawnTime.setText("");
    }
```

**The error**

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
                                                       at com.example.mariusz.astroweather.SunFragment.clearText(SunFragment.java:99)
```

Comment: When is clearText() called?

Comment: please show us your complete fragment code

Answer (score 0):

Check and trace inside your `onCreateView()` and see if `sunSetTime` TextView is not Null. It might happen that you have alternate layouts for `R.layout.fragment_sun` which might does not include `sunSetTime` TextView.
If this is not the case, it might happen that you call clearText() before `onCreateView`.

Comment: ```sunSetTime``` isn't null in attached debugger image.

Comment: @ZeeshanShabbir Did you take this snapshot when you were inside `clearText()` or it is for another moment of execution?